# How to construct a list

Tags: c#, list

How can I construct a list with two dimensions?

I tried this like python

```
Tuple<string,int> tpl = new Tuple<string,int>("",0);

List<Tuple> lst = new List<Tuple>();
```

and this

```
List<string,int> lst = new <string,int> ();
```

with no luck.

Comment: You can always create a class with those two properties and use it's type to create your list.

Comment: You have to propagate the generic. So if you defined `Tuple<string, int>`, then your list must look like `List<Tuple<string, int>>`. So basically, your construction statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the tuple item types :

```
var lst = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
```

Or you could use a class (Which allows you to name the properties):

```
class Data
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string OtherProp { get; set; }
}

var lst = new List<Data>();
```

Or if you are using C# 7 and have the `System.ValueTuple` package installed you could use the new tuples syntax:

```
var lst = new List<(string, int)>();
```

or with names :

```
var lst = new List<(string name, int id)>();
// Adding
lst.Add(("test", 1));
lst.Add((name: "test", id: 1));
// Member access 
var name = lst[0].name;
// Destructuring 
var (name, id) = lst[0];
```

C# 7 syntax is the nicer one of these, but might not be available in all contexts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `List<Tuple<string, int>>`;

```
var example = new List<Tuple<string, int>>
{
    Tuple.Create("", 0),
    Tuple.Create("Some other element", 60)
};
```

Comment: hehehe, almost the same answer as me, but with yours I have learned a way of creating a tuple I wasn't aware of :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `List<Tuple<string,int>>`:

```
var twoDimensionsList = new List<Tuple<string,int>>
{
    new Tuple<string,int>("something", 0),
    new Tuple<string,int>("something else", 1),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
        var list = new List<TupleType>
        {
                new TupleType
                {
                    Key = 1,
                    Value = "Sample"
                }
        };
        //list[0].Key
        //list[0].Value
```

`TupleType` class;

```
public class TupleType
{
    public int Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you are targeting .NET 4 or superior, I think it is better to use the generic `Tuple` type included in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like the `Tuple<String, Int32>` solution proposed by other users:

```
List<Tuple<String, Int32>> myList = new List<Tuple<String, Int32>>
{
    Tuple.Create("A", 1),
    Tuple.Create("B", 2)
};
```

This is how I would implement your requirement, and this is my preferred approach:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Int32 MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public String MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}

List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

Tuples are great for `internal usage`. As long as you can control and maintain the context in which they are being used and you have a full understanding of their structure and parameters, they are more than fine. On a `public API`, unfortunately, they are less effective because of the lack of naming: they would force the consumer to guess their behavior or look up the documentation.

**EDIT**

In `C# 7`, you can now use them with named properties, so they became a good option.

Comment: Pre C# 7, tuples were unusable in my opinion because of the lack of naming, but the new syntax that allows names is pretty nice

Comment: I totally agree but I never tried C# 7, so I wasn't aware of that feature. I don't code in C# frequently anymore.